# Regex routing in Python using Tornado framework

Tags: python, regex, routes, tornado

i currently have this in my routing:

(r"/admin", AdminController.Index ),
(r"/admin/", AdminController.Index ),

how do i merge them with just one line and have admin and admin/ go to AdminController.Index?

i know this could be achieved via regex, but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: You could redirect every route not ending with `/` to the one ending with.

Comment: i would ask how to do that, but let me do some research first before i ask that question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this: r'/admin/?' or r'/admin/{0,1}? Pay attention that I'm only talking about regex, don't know if this would work in Django.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that didn't work...

Since this is a regular expression it's doing matching, a regex of `/admin/?` will match `/admin/`, `/admin`, and `/admin/foo`.

```
import re
bool(re.match("/admin/","/admin/foo"))
>>> True
bool(re.match("/admin/?$","/admin/foo"))
>>> False
```

What you really want to do is make sure your regular expression is finished.

```
r'/admin/?$'
```

Is more likely what you're looking for.

Comment: unfortunately ... my calls to my js and css are still not working as they are now looking at different locations

admin is looking at /styles.css

while

admin/ is looking at /css/styles.css

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what's working/not working and where they should be routed.  It might be that you're missing a leading '/' on your <link href="/..." ...> html.

Comment: i finally got it to your tip to work, i simply added "@tornado.web.addslashes" before the definitions :) thanks again koblas